# Is there any advantage in creating a clustered index - if we are not going to query/search for records based on that column?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

I am doing a review of some DB tables that were created in our project and came across this. The table contains an Identity column (ID) which is the primarykey for the table and a clustered index has been defined using this ID column. But when I look at the SPROC that retrieves records from this table, I see that the ID column is never used in the query and they query the records based on a USERID column (this column is not unique) and there can be multiple records for the same USERID.

So my question is there any advantage/purpose in creating a clustered index when we know that the records wont be queried with that column?

Comment: A PK column is very likely a target of a number of `JOIN`s that'll greatly profit from a clustered index there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your table is mis-designed.  Someone apparently thought every table needs a primary key and the primary key is the clustered index.  Adding a system-generated unique number as an identifier just adds noise if that number isn't used anywhere.  Noise in the clustered index is unhelpful, to say the least.

They are different concepts, by the way.  A primary key is a data modeling concern, a logical concept.  An index is a physical design issue.  A SQL DBMS must support primary keys, but need not have any indexes, clustered or no.

If `USERID` is what is usually used to search the table, it should be in your clustered index.  The clustered index need not be unique and need not be the primary key.   I would look at the data carefully to see if some combination of `USERID` and another column (or two, or more) form a unique identifier for the row.  If so, I'd make that the primary key (and clustered index), with `USERID` as the first column.  If query analysis showed that many queries use only `USERID` and nothing else (for existence testing) I might create a separate index just of `USERID`.

If no combination of columns constitutes a unique identifier, you have logical problem, to wit: *what does the row mean*?  What aspect of the real world does it represent?

A basic tenet of the Relational Model is that elements in a relation (rows in a table) are unique, that each one *identifies* something.  If two rows are identical, they identify the same thing.  What does it mean to delete one of them?  Is the thing that they both identify still there, or not?  If it is, what purpose did the 2nd row serve?

I hope that gives you another way to think about clustered indexes and keys.  I wouldn't be surprised if you find other tables that could be improved, too.

Answer (score 3):

If the `IDENTITY` column is never used in `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses, or referenced by foreign keys, perhaps USERID should be a clustered primary key. I would question the need for the ID column at all in that case.

The best choice for the clustered index depends much on how the table is queried. If the majority of queries are by USERID, then it should probably be a unique clustered index (or clustered unique constraint) and the `ID` column non-clustered.

Keep in mind that the clustered index key is implicitly included in all non-clustered indexes as the row locator.  The implication is that non-clustered indexes may more likely cover queries and non-clustered index leaf node pages wider as a result.

Comment: These are my concerns for adding USERID as a clustered index :

1. SQL server will be adding the uniquefier to make the index unique. I read that it might be a performance constraint? 
2. Also there can be lot of add's/delete's of UID's - wouldnt that be a concern when it is a clustered index?

Comment: I thought USERID was unique.  In that case SQL Server won't add a uniqueifier.  I'm not aware of a uniquifier being a performance concern, other than 4 bytes of additional storage. Incremental clustered index keys have both pros and cons with respect to insert performance. The short answer is I wouldn't be overly concerned with non-incremental key performance unless you are using spinning media with few spindles and expecting hundreds of millions of users.